# How to convert SOAP XML to Java Object in android

Tags: java, xml, soap, xml-parsing, onvif

I want parse and convert the SOAP XML response to JAVA objects.
I thought of using J-WS and JAXB to do the same by creating the client stub code. But J-WS and JAXB are not part of Android AOSP hence I have to do it manually.

Following is the example of soap xml response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<tds:GetSystemDateAndTime/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Response to device.GetSystemDateAndTime
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema"
xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<tds:GetSystemDateAndTimeResponse>
<tds:SystemDateAndTime>
<tt:DateTimeType>NTP</tt:DateTimeType>  
<tt:DaylightSavings>true</tt:DaylightSavings>
<tt:TimeZone>
<tt:TZ>CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0</tt:TZ>
   </tt:TimeZone>
<tt:UTCDateTime>
<tt:Time>
<tt:Hour>15</tt:Hour>
<tt:Minute>52</tt:Minute>
<tt:Second>25</tt:Second>
</tt:Time>
<tt:Date>
<tt:Year>2010</tt:Year>
<tt:Month>10</tt:Month>
<tt:Day>29</tt:Day>
</tt:Date>
</tt:UTCDateTime>
<tt:LocalDateTime>
<tt:Time>
<tt:Hour>17</tt:Hour>
<tt:Minute>52</tt:Minute>
<tt:Second>25</tt:Second>
</tt:Time>
<tt:Date>
<tt:Year>2010</tt:Year>
<tt:Month>10</tt:Month>
<tt:Day>29</tt:Day>
</tt:Date>
</tt:LocalDateTime>
</tds:SystemDateAndTime>
</tds:GetSystemDateAndTimeResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use 3rd party SimpleXML framework which uses Apache 2.0license.
For detailed info & examples, refer the below link - 
http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it by hand, you should generate the conversion code by using a tool able to understand the wsdl files with the ONVIF specifications.

Since you are talking about java and android, probably you should check [ksoap2-android](https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android). I am not an expert of java, but there are some examples available, such [this one](https://github.com/hhbgk/WebService).